# Why is C# not throwing exception which occured inside a local function of an async function?

Tags: c#, uwp

I got this function:

```
public async Task<bool> TryPlayElseStop(int reciterId, int chapterId) {
    this.chapterId = chapterId;
    var file = await RecitationUtils.TryGetAudioFile(reciterId, chapterId);
    if (file != null) {
        Play(file); // there should be an exception thrown here
        return true;
    } else {
        Utils.Toast("Download the file first in the Recitation menu");
        Stop();
        return false;
    }
}

private void Play(Tuple<MyFile, RealmRecitationFile> file) {
    if (mediaPlayer == null)
        InitMediaPlayer();
    ResetCallbacks();
    mediaPlayer.SetSource(file.Item1);
    FileCurrentlyPlaying = file.Item2;
    AppUtils.UpdateListeningHistory(chapterId);
    UiClients.ForEach(x => x.OnSurahPlayed(chapterId));

    void InitMediaPlayer() {
        mediaPlayer = new MyMediaPlayer {IsLoopingEnabled = false};
        // the app continues even though I'm explicitly 
        // throwing this exception for debugging purposes
        throw new NullReferenceException(); 
        playerTimer = new MyTimer(1_000); // the actual exception occurs inside this constructor
        playerTimer.Start();
        UiClients.ForEach(x => x.OnPlayerInitialized());
    }

    // ...
}
```

When I call the TryPlayElseStop method, there should be raised a NullReferenceException. However, the app doesn't raise one, but just continues running as if nothing happens.

I tried debugging it but as soon as I step over the line where the exception should be thrown, the debugging stops, which is what I'm expecting. However, the app doesn't stop. Only the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I call the TryPlayElseStop method, there should be raised a NullReferenceException.

No, when you call the `TryPlayElseStop` method, it should return a faulted task. A method declared with the `async` modifier *never* throws an exception synchronously, even if it gets to the exception while executing synchronously (before the first await that has to "pause").

You haven't shown how `TryPlayElseStop` is being called, but either awaiting the returned task or calling `Wait()` or `Result` on it *will* throw an exception (assuming `Play` itself throws an exception as you've commented). Perhaps you're not awaiting the result of `TryPlayElseStop` anywhere?

Comment: Just checked my code and it seems I'm not awaiting it. Thank you. I didn't know it can be this serious if you don't await. I see now why the compiler warns me of not awaiting async methods.